# How to combine multiple table results into one using FetchXml

Tags: report, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

I am using CRM 2013 Online. I want to generate a report on Opportunity entity like below:

```
CampaignCode    Open Opportunity Count  Won Opportunity Count   Lost Opportunity Count
    CC1                    3                       5                       1
    CC2                    0                       2                       3
```

Here the results are group by on "CampaignCode" column which is a lookup. Using FetchXml I am able to get 3 tables like below:

```
CampaignCode    Open Opportunity Count
    CC1                3        
    CC2                0
CampaignCode    Won Opportunity Count
    CC1                5        
    CC2                2
CampaignCode    Lost Opportunity Count
    CC1                1        
    CC2                3
```

But I am not able to combine these 3 tables into 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For what i know it's not possible to merge multiple datasets in a single table. I will give your question a plus because I'm interested in this too.